# How to set the image for a button located within a UICollectionView's Cell which is triple embedded?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uibutton

I am on the main view controller which is one of five, embedded in a UITabBarController.

In the main view controller there is a table view with several rows, each of the rows has a view controller embedded in it. All the view controller's which are embedded in each row of the UITableView contain embedded collection views. The button I want to change the image on is located in a cell in the aforementioned, embedded UICollectionView.

When a user executes a specific selected UIAction from UIContextMenuConfigurationDelegate, which calls a function that is supposed to change the button's UIImage's, it executes but the button's image doesn't change until I scroll in the collection view.

I'm not sure how to fix this? Should I pass data somehow? Confused.

Comment: you need to reload the specific cell after setting the image like `let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0)  collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])`

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work.

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Ok, I will update the question.

Comment: @MBT - this is the correct answer. Please submit it as it should be.